# Load most basic website using VS WebBrowser

Tags: c#, httprequest, webbrowser-control

I am creating a program that will schedule classes for me for my upcoming semester, and I have everything working in regards to inputting my username, password, and Schedule ID, however I want it to work as fast as possible. I did some research into disabling images from being downloaded, but have yet to come to a conclusion.

So basically, I want to request the website, but I don't want none of the 'fancy' UI such as images, animations, etc... I just want plain text and the respective fields. Is this even possible using VS WebBrowser? Would this be along the lines of just gathering the HTML and no CSS/JS?

Thanks for reading! Any hints or help in the right direction would be muchas gracias!

Comment: You can use WebClient/HttpClient in order to send requests to the site. This will work much faster

Comment: @Aleksey L. Would sending data be very different using this method? Meaning, does the WebClient/HttpClient have .getAtribute() methods and InvokeMember() methods?

Comment: Yep it's different. With web client you're not invoking js methods, rather sending raw http requests

Comment: Can I authenticate myself and perform button clicks with radio buttons selected this way?

Comment: Basically you can mimic any browser activity. You can use chrome's dev tools or fiddler to sniff what actually sent to server. It can be little bit tricky if you're not familiar with this stuff

Comment: Note taken. Ill look into those programs. Do you have any sources or snipets I can look at by chance on any of the steps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191159/procedural-httpwebrequest or could I forward you here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is not possible in a "nice way." The images are loaded and requested *after* the html loads, and so there would have to be a way to disconnect or abort the request, just after we recieve all of the html. Digging around, you *cannot* do this natively in VS' WebBrowser.